# How to Subtract in MySQL Database one table value based on another table value?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have this Query, this one is working fine

```
$qu= "UPDATE comp_controller SET num_comp=(num_comp-(SELECT num_comp FROM alloted_comp WHERE comp_name="Arduino uno")) WHERE comp_name ="Arduino uno"";
```

I have used predefined value in comp_name but have to get comp_name from following query

```
$sql="INSERT INTO alloted_comp (comp_type,comp_name,num_comp)VALUES ('$_POST[comp_type]','$_POST[comp_name]','$_POST[num_comp]') ";
```

how to get insert values in first query from second query

**Update:**

I modified my code

```
$type = isset($_POST['comp_type'])? $_POST['comp_type'] : '';
$name = isset($_POST['comp_name'])? $_POST['comp_name'] :'';
$comp = isset($_POST['num_comp]'])? $_POST['num_comp]'] :'';


$sql="INSERT INTO alloted_comp (comp_type,comp_name,num_comp) 
VALUES ('$_POST[comp_type]','$_POST[comp_name]',$_POST[num_comp])
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE num_comp=num_comp+'$_POST[num_comp]'";

$qu= mysql_query("UPDATE comp_controller SET num_comp=
(num_comp-(SELECTnum_comp FROM alloted_comp 
 WHERE comp_name='$name'))WHERE comp_name ='$name' ");
```

Now i'm facing new problem with substation,  If i enter num_comp 1, it will subtracting with value as 2 or 3 or some times with garbage value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the variable in the `UPDATE` query just like you do in the `INSERT` query.

```
$qu= "UPDATE comp_controller 
      SET num_comp=(num_comp-(
        SELECT num_comp FROM alloted_comp 
        WHERE comp_name='$_POST[comp_name]')) 
      WHERE comp_name ='$_POST[comp_name]'";
```

Note that this is vulnerable to SQL-injection. You should learn to use prepared queries, or at least use `mysqli_real_escape_string` to escape the variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.....for second query

```
$type = isset($_POST['comp_type'])? $_POST['comp_type'] : '';
$name = isset($_POST['comp_name'])? $_POST['comp_name'] :'';
$comp = isset($_POST['num_comp]'])? $_POST['num_comp]'] :'';

$sql="INSERT INTO alloted_comp (comp_type,comp_name,num_comp) VALUES('$type','$name','$comp') ";
```

For update query....

```
$qu= "UPDATE comp_controller SET num_comp=(num_comp-(SELECT num_comp FROM alloted_comp WHERE comp_name='$name')) WHERE comp_name ='$name' ";
```

Comment: use prepared queries, or  mysqli_real_escape_string to escape the variables.

Comment: @HikmatSijapati Thank you for your answer, working fine but have problem with subtraction. If i enter num_comp 1, it will subtracting with value as 2 or 3 or some times num_comp in comp_controller becomes 0

Comment: `SELECT num_comp FROM alloted_comp WHERE comp_name='$name'`..see this query you are selecting value on the basis  of `comp_name`...i think this query must changed to `SELECT num_comp FROM alloted_comp WHERE num_comp='$comp '`.